# Thawte SSL free Certificate not detected - jetty server

Tags: java, ssl, jetty-9

I generated the keystore : 
**keytool -genkeypair -alias jetty -keyalg RSA -validity 30 -keystore keystore.jks** 
 
I generated a CSR : 
**keytool -certreq -alias jetty -file certreq.csr -keystore keystore.jks**
 
then I use this CSR to get a free SSL certificate, after that they send 3 certificates, which I added to my keystore : 
**keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file root.cer -keystore myKeystore**
**keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate-file intermediate.cer -keystore myKeystore**
**keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias trial -file trial.cer -keystore myKeystore**

I use jetty 9 so here's the config for it in jetty-ssl.xml :

```
   <Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="ironhide"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default="ironhide"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default="ironhide"/></Set>
```

But when I restart the server, it still shows as it is self-signed with https on the browser with **red X mark**

here's the keystore:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

**root, Nov 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 51:51:B8:63:8A:4C:1F:15:54:56:ED:37:C9:10:35:CA:
D3:01:B9:36 

intermediate, Nov 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): BE:D1:D1:4E:25:A7:94:36:83:9E:4B:A7:CD:84:48:96:
B7:0A:7F:B0

trial, Nov 16, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): DF:A1:52:F0:60:31:4C:DB:0C:61:3D:CA:C4:A6:85:FE:
D4:4C:CD:04

getlinked, Nov 14, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 2C:82:F7:E8:09:C2:7D:7C:71:9E:86:C0:EC:85:22:AE:
20:7D:43:14**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your alias, when you generated the private key + CSR was "getlinked", the signed certificate file is trial.cer (PEM encoded), and that the intermediate certificate from the CA is intermediate.cer (PEM encoded).

If your certificate is just the certificate only, you may need to "chain" the certificate by concatenating the intermediate certificate to it.

Unix:

```
cat trial.cer intermediate.cer > chained.cer
```

Windows:

```
copy /b trial.cer+intermediate.cer chained.cer
```

Then, based on the alias used to generate the CSR

```
keytool -import -alias getlinked -file chained.cer -keystore myKeystore
```

Add a set for the Alias property.

```
<Set name="CertAlias">getlinked</Set>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, jetty doesnt restart after I add, and if you can specify what Alias exactly, Also I think that there's nothing wrong with jetty config , thank you

Comment: Change that to CertAlias ... Confused it with tomcat

Comment: still not working, even when I add all the certificates and in order, it's like its ignoring them, and just showing a selfsigned certificate..

Comment: Do I need to merge key with certificate ?

Comment: I'm not following - "merge key with certificate". Your keystore should have, at the very least, a PrivateKeyEntry containing the private key and the certificate you got signed

Comment: I added my keystore, it contains the private key, the rootCA, intermediatCA, and the trial certificate

Comment: You have a SEPARATE trustedCert entry named `trial`, not `mydomain` as you first said, so it is NOT in the privatekey entry, which is named `getlinked` not `jetty` as you first said. You need to `-importcert` the cert for the server (mydomain.crt) TO THE ALIAS OF THE PRIVATEKEY here `getlinked`.

Comment: Im sorry, this is a new keystore with new certificates from a different provider,i will change the import command...how do I import the cert to the Alias of the private key ?

Comment: keytool -importcert -alias (alias) -keystore (keystore) ... read keytool -importcert -h for more information and parameters.

Comment: isnt this command equivalent of this one : keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file root.cer -keystore myKeystore
 ??

Comment: Ok I'm really confused by what you are attempting.  You should be able to have a keystore with the private key entry that you generated the CSR from to be signed. When you got the certificate reply from the authority, you should have been able to import that cert to the private key entry alias. Using "-trustcacerts" most likely was not necessary because your issued certificate will not contain the basic constraint "CA" as true. If you attempt to import the certificate reply and it complains that a path chain cannot be established, you may need to concatenate any intermediate issuer certs to it

Comment: I have the kystore with the private key in it :getlinked, Nov 14, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 2C:82:F7:E8:09:C2:7D:7C:71:9E:86:C0:EC:85:22:AE: 20:7D:43:14, I generated CSR, I got the trial certificates, and imported them to the keystore, it was successful, no problem whatsoever,when I restart the server, the browser shows it as untrusted, certificate path has only mydomain in it with keystore validity -validity 30, and I really dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys, I solved the problem, so the issue is that the "MYDOMAIN" certificate should have the same alias as the private key in the keystore,
 
keytool -genkeypair -alias **jetty** -keyalg RSA -validity 30 -keystore keystore.jks 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias **jetty** -file trial.cer -keystore myKeystore

this worked for me, I tried it with a bought certificate and it's all good.

thank you guys for your help.